# Accessing cookies when the browser is in private mode

Tags: wordpress, cookies, incognito-mode

I've been setting a cookie using a header template file in wordpress. If I'm logged out of wp, and in incognito mode/private browsing, the cookie is visible in the developer console, but is unavailable to my server ($_COOKIE is empty), and I'm not sure why.

However, the cookie is accessible when I'm logged in, and in incognito mode, and both logged in and out when browsing regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue here was that the host for my site provides a caching layer with nginx, and the cookies don't make their way through to apache. I fixed the problem using a javascript solution instead.